# AWS Amplify/Cognito Tenant Selection at login

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I am currently using AWS Cognito and it's hosted UI to manage user login. All my users sit in a single pool, which has a number of different app clients registered. Our users are grouped into different organisations and for the most part a single user (or email address) is only associated with a single organisation, so this setup works very well. A small subset of users are associated to multiple organisations. Associated to a particular organisation is managed by a backend service rather than using Cognito attributes and/or groups.

We are already using the pre token generation Lambda trigger to inject claims into our tokens to denote which organisation a user belongs to which is then used downstream in our backend services to control which database is hit when a user makes an API request (we use single tenant databases).

I need to design a mechanism that will allow the users who belong to multiple organisations to select which organisation they want to login as (ie select which tenant they want to use for that session) at auth time. I know this will be impossible to do with the Hosted Cognito UI but I'm wondering if this is something that can be done with AWS Amplify along with a custom login app and using custom auth challenges. The flow would be something like this:

1. Username/password provided
2. Custom auth challenge lambda fires which detects whether the user has a 1-1 relationship to a single organisation (in which case we can log them straight in) or a 1-many relationship to multiple orgs.
3. In the latter case above, the auth challenge returns a collection of organisations that a user is allowed to log in to back to the app which displays them in a picker control (drop down or similar)
4. User selects their tenant and this information is sent to the auth challenge response and the login continues.
5. A key step after this would be ensuring that the custom challenge responses make it through to the pre token generation Lambda function so it knows which organisation the user is logging into.

I'm a backend developer and have had no exposure to Amplify at all, I just need to know if this is theoretically possible before I invest too much time into it.

Can anybody with Amplify experience confirm if what I describe would be possible using Amplify and a custom auth React app?

Thanks

Comment: This is non-trivial with cognito. I really think you'd benefit from separating your authentication from authorization. Use Cognito strictly for authentication because the lack of flexibility makes it virtually unworkable for authorization in anything but the simplest apps. The way I'd approach it is by going through a token exchange process i.e. cognito ID token used to create an API access token for a given tenant with a custom authorization endpoint.

Comment: Any luck? I'm having the same problem...

Comment: Nope, however I'm literally on a call with AWS right now!